# Turn-off debugger in Emacs SLIME

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime, sbcl

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074586/how-to-turn-off-the-debugger-in-sbcl), I can customize the variable `*DEBUGGER-HOOK*` so that it falls back to toplevel (in REPL) instead of the debugger. I've added this line to my ~/.sbclrc and it's all fine when I start sbcl from command line.

```
(setf *debugger-hook* #'(lambda (c h) (declare (ignore h)) (print c) (abort)))
```

But, the above doesn't work for Emacs SLIME. Whenever I compile/load a file (C-c C-k), it still invokes the debugger (with options like abort calculation, restart, enter new value etc.). How can I ask SLIME to just print the error message and throw me back to toplevel? Yea, it's with SBCL and the same ~/.sbclrc as before. Looks like SLIME doesn't respect a user's setting of `*DEBUGGER-HOOK*`.

Comment: I imagine `*DEBUGGER-HOOK*` refers to the implementation's debugger. It is part of the standard. So, I don't think SLIME is required to respect it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, it is part of the Common Lisp standard: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_debugg.htm

Answer (score 1):

As per http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Other-configurables.html setting `SWANK:*GLOBAL-DEBUGGER*` to nil in `~/.swank.lisp` file should force SLIME to not replace `*DEBUGGER-HOOK*` to `SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK` (which shows list of restarts etc.), but it somehow doesn't work for me, i.e. `SWANK:*GLOBAL-DEBUGGER*` is nil but anyway `*DEBUGGER-HOOK*` is replaced by SLIME. Maybe you'll be more lucky.

As a workaround I can propose to set `*DEBUGGER-HOOK*` to whatever you want in the slime-repl buffer manually, which is worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work, just like for you. I put `(setq SWANK:*GLOBAL-DEBUGGER* nil)` in ~/.swank.lisp but has no effect. I can set `*debugger-hook*` in the REPL, but that's clumsy to do every time. I'm thinking of asking this in the slime-devel mailing list, if no one on SO gets it.